# pyspark dataframe count of where clause value is equals to

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

following is the sample dataframe

I have one column in with 'id' and i need new dataframe with count number considering where clause where vaule is equal to "number", new dataframe with vaule and count

source df and required newdf with count of df
[image: source df and required newdf with count of df]

Any suggestions:

Answer (score 1):

Just group by and count:

```
newdf = df.groupBy('Id').count()
```